# Regular Expressions Excluding Specific Special Characters and allowing some special characters

Tags: regex

I need to create a RegEx for field validation that allows for all Alpha Numeric digits excluding all special characters except (#-/.).  For Example: apples&pears would not pass matching due to the "&", however apples#pears would pass since "#" is part of the whitelist of special characters.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the language/platform that you are using the regex?

Answer (score 1):

So you need a regex that matches digits and not special characters?

How about

```
/\d*/
```

---

Maybe you want to include letters and the `_` character too.

then you'd do

```
/\w*/
```

Perhaps you want to get more fancy, and exclude a blacklist of specific characters

```
/[^ABC]*/  // this one will exclude A, B, and C
```

Maybe you think blacklists are short-sited and want to whitelist characters, just leave out the `^`

```
/[A-Z0-9]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z#-\/\.]+$/
```

That is: all the characters in your string are "not (letters (a-zA-Z), and the characters you specified)".

Answer (score 0):

so all digits : 0-9 and the others '.' and '/' need an escape (in many implementations) 
so:

```
 /[-0-9#\/\.]*/
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This solution does work for digits and special characters.  In my original post I should have noted "alphanumeric" charaters.

Answer (score 0):

> RegEx that allows all Alpha Numeric excluding all special characters except :

`#-/.`

Have a try with:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9#/.-]+$
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The solution above allows for the text "apple>" where the ">" character should not be allowed for a match.

Comment: @user3325120: No, it doesn't. How do you use it?

Comment: Hello M42, your solution above is capturing all the strings/characters correctly.  Would you happen to know how to test to make sure that the input text is not empty?

Comment: Hello, I just realized during testing that the pattern above does find a match for the string "apples*", where the "*" character is not part of the approved character list.

Comment: Hello M42...the pattern that you provided does catch the "*" in the string as not a valid match.  During my testing I had made a change to the pattern that provided me with a false positive.

Comment: @user3325120: No it doesn't, the `*` is not in the character class. This regex matches only string that have at least one of the specified characters and nothing else. Edit your question in order to show how you're using it. May be you don't use the anchors `^` and `$`.

Comment: @ma42 - I am not sure; the `-` (literaly) in `[]` without ESC is only allowed at first pos like here ´[-A-Za-z0-9#\.]´ I think. It prob depends on implementation

Comment: @halfbit: The dash `-` can be at first or last position of the character class without escaping, and every where when it is escaped.